# X contains all its accumulation points $\iff$ X contains all its closure points.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

From (say Apostol Analysis) we find the following two facts:

1. X is closed iff it contains ALL its accumulation points.
2. X is closed iff it contains ALL its boundary points.

So, one must conclude that X contains all its accumulation points $\iff$  X contains all its closure points. How to show this fact (without claiming X is closed) ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226319/boundary-points-isolation-points-accumulation-points

Comment: Its not the same.

Comment: That's why I said similar. You want to show that $X$ containing all accumulation points is equivalent to $X$ containing all closure points. A good way to do this is to show that if $a\in X$ is an accumulation point then $a\in X$ is a boundary point...

Comment: But that's not true: Consider X= [0,1)U(1,2]. The set of accumulation points is [0,2] and the set of boundary points is {0,1,2}.

Answer (score 0):

$\rightarrow$

Suppose $X$ contains all its accumulation points, then assume that there is a boundary point $x$ which isn't belong to $X$. Hence at every neighbourhood of $x$ there are points of $X$ and of its complement hence $x$ is an accumulation point of $X$, but all accumulation points belong to $X$. Contradiction. Therefore all boundary points belong to $X$

Following that way we can prove the inverse statement.

Comment: I agree this argument,

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ contains all its accumulation points, let $x$ be a boundary point of $A$. If $x \notin A$, then $A$ is an accumulation point of $A$ (as every neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A \setminus \{x\}$) that's not in $A$ which was not the case. So $x \in A$ and so $A$ contains all its boundary points.

If $A$ contains all its boundary points, let $x$ be an accumulation point of $A$.
If $x \notin A$ every neighbourhood of $x$ contains a point in $A$ (by being an accumulation point) and a point not in $A$ ($x$ itself e.g.). So $x$ is boundary point. But $A$ contains all its boundary points, so contradiction and so $A$ contains all its accumulation points.

So both conditions are indeed equivalent.

Comment: I agree completely with the second argument (second paragraph). But I think the first fails if the set A is made  only of isolated points.

Comment: @SamuelDíaz if $A$ only has isolated points what goes wrong? The argument still works.

Comment: If A has only isolated points, the set of its acummulation points is empty and its boundary is A itself. So if x doesn't belog to A it's not true that x is a acummulation point of A.

Comment: @SamuelDíaz So we get a correct contradiction. If $x$ is a boundary point outside $A$ (assumption!) it is an accumulation point (always true) and thus inside $A$ (because we assume $A$ contains its accumulation points). So $x$ must lie inside $A$ (because the assumption it was not led to a contradiction), which was exactly what we needed to show.

Comment: I got you point! It was hard to do it. Is this (my post) a relevant result? I didn't see it in any text or forum.

Comment: @SamuelDíaz both are common characterisations of closed sets. So of course they’re equivalent as they both say a set is closed. The direct argument is indeed seldom seen, but not very important in its own right I would say.

Comment: Any suggested book for real analysis?